# Sorting in Javascript for parsed JSON is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, frontend

Apologies, my skill in Javascript is not amazing and hence, have the following question:

I am trying to parse a string as JSON object and then sort it. However, when I execute the function that I have got it is saying the sort function is not correct. My function as follows:

```
function () {
    var controlerValue = control.val();
    if (multiSelectBehavior != "none") {
        return controlerValue == "" ? [] : JSON.parse(controlerValue).sort(function (a, b) { return a - b });
    }
    return JSON.parse(controlerValue);
}
```

Example of control.val() (this is a type string) is as follows:

"[11,3,4,6,18,9,11,10,13]"

"" (blank)

How to sort the JSON object as shown in the function above?

Comment: `"11, 4, 9, 3"` is not valid JSON - `"\"11, 4, 9, 3\""` is though ... but JSON.parse will return a String for that JSON ... the fact that you don't get an error suggests that `control.val()` may be `""` .. but then, the JSON.parse would fail, since `[]` is not valid JSON

Comment: you need an array, not a string with values separated by comma.

Comment: Why use `JSON.parse` at all isn't `controlerValue` just a string? Can't you just do `controlerValue.split(",").sort(...`

Comment: you can just split the string into an array and sort it and again join to return string . something like this controlerValue.split(",").sort().join(",")

Comment: I think the return value is expected to be a JSON object or else the whole feature will fail

Comment: [There is no such thing as a JSON object](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/). Once the JSON is parsed, it becomes a plain old JavaScript object (array, whatever).

Comment: @Bravo so how to approach this? the input value could be "\"11, 4, 9, 3\"" or "" (empty) thank you in advance.

Comment: if it's `"\"11, 4, 9, 3\""` then return `JSON.parse(controlerValue).split(/,\s*/).map(Number).sort((a, b) => a-b)` if it's `""` return `[]`

Comment: my bad, I had put the wrong input data in and have updated the question. @Bravo the input data is either like: "[11,3,4,6,18,9,11,10,13]" or "" (empty)

Comment: then `JSON.parse(controlerValue).sort((a, b) => a-b)` works (as long as the data does NOT include the `"` in `"[1,2,3]"`

Comment: @NinaScholz I have updated the question. my intial input data was wrong.

Comment: Now you have valid JSON. Just check for empty string first (since that's not valid JSON) and decide  what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use [substring function](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp) to get rid of the "[" and "]"
2. Use the [split function](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) to get the numbers
3. User the [sort function](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp) to sort the numbers, passing it the right function to sort the numbers and you are done.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  var controllerValue = "[11,3,4,6,18,9,11,10,13]";
    var numbers = controllerValue.substring(1, controllerValue.length -1).split(',')
    numbers.sort(function(a, b){return a-b});
    numbers.forEach(number => console.log('number: ' + number));
});
```

Here is a [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Meziano/q5p8jumL/3/)

Comment: HI @[Somdip Dey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4190159/somdip-dey), may be I didn't understand your problem?

Comment: HI @Somdip Dey, Is this not what you are looking for?
Please try to give a chance to my answer: it took me time to write it.